# Transição automática de imagens no slider com css

Tags: html, css, slider, transição

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo no Imasters e na parte de desenvolvimento em geral e estou com uma dúvida bem simples, não julguem kkk

Criei esse slider descrito logo abaixo e não consigo fazer a troca de imagens automática.

Por exemplo, a cada 3 segundos a imagem fazer um fade out e entrar outra com fade in básico, ou mesmo deslizar pro lado. A animação não tem tanta importancia.

O que queria mesmo era fazer com que funcione o código pra automatizar a troca de imagens.

Alguem poderia por favor me dar uma luz? Tentei algumas coisas aqui mas não consegui :/

Segue o codigo:

```css
/﻿*------------------- SLIDER FRONT PAGE - NOVIDADES ----------------------*/


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);


.div-slider{
width: auto;
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
}
.slides-front {
    padding: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 370px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides-front * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides-front input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 370px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: 375px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3, {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="div-slider">
  <ul class="slides-front">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked="">
    <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://10.0.2.220/draftfile.php/961/user/draft/587036133/slider-front-1.png">
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">‹</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">›</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://10.0.2.220/draftfile.php/961/user/draft/587036133/slider-front-2.png">
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">‹</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">›</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://10.0.2.220/draftfile.php/961/user/draft/587036133/slider-front-3.png">
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">‹</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">›</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>﻿
```

Qualquer dica é bem vinda. Agradeço desde ja (:

Vlw

Comment: Da forma como vc motou vc só vai conseguir resolver isso com JS ou jQuery. Pois vc tem uma interação usando essas Setas e as Bolinhas para fazer aparecer e desaparecer o proxímo slide, então com CSS vc não consegue fazer essa troca automática, a não ser que seja algo bem mais simples que isso, sem esses "controles" que o usuário usa para trocar clicando nas seta. Se vc quiser usar Bootstrap aqui tem um exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293048/como-alterar-o-efeito-padr%C3%A3o-do-slide-do-bootstrap-para-fade/293124#293124

Comment: Aqui tem mais dois exemplos de galerias com fade, podem sem os controles pro usuário ficar passando de um para o outro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288556/bug-no-slideshow-se-ficar-muito-tempo-fora-do-separador/288581#288581 e aqui tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267212/fiz-3-slidesshow-mas-entre-os-slidesshows-esta-a-haver-um-espa%C3%A7o/267251#267251

Comment: Entendi. Vou dar uma olhada e tentar implantar o JS entao. Mas se tiver uma solução com CSS, eu tiro as setas de "controle" e deixo somente as bolinhas. Tem como?

Comment: Ou no caso tenho que tirar todos os codigos de "controle" e deixar só css automatico na troca de imagens?


Obrigado pela atençao! (:

Comment: Cara é isso mesmo, como os controle vc não vai conseguir fazer. Agora se for apenas as imagens trocando com fade ai vc resolve só com CSS, tipo um slideshow, mas sem esses artifícios de navegação pelo clique...  Nesses links que comentei tem alguns exemplos de como fazer o slideshow automático.

Comment: Demorow. É que eu por algum motivo achei que daria pra fazer alguma coisa com CSS apenas, usando animation ou transition de img, sei lá. Mas se nao tem jeito, nao tem jeito. Vou tentar implantar JS primeiramente, se ficar muito complicado eu deixo só no transition no CSS sem controle mesmo.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela força!

Comment: Cara vc até poderia colocar um @keyframes na sua imagem para ela desaparecer digamos em 3 segundos, o problema é que ela vai desaparecer mas a próxima imagem não vai aparecer.... Isso pq para ela aparecer vc precisa clicar em algum elemento da navegação... vc não consegue fazer esse evento de "clicamento" automático entender. Esse é um tipo de interação que só o usuário pode fazer, ou então com JS pode ser que vc resolva isso como no Exemplo do Bootstrap que coloquei no link ai acima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas com CSS você não irá conseguir, mas com um pequeno código em jQuery você consegue automatizar o processo usando `setInterval()`, que é um temporizador em intervalos que irá chamar uma função que irá ir checando o próximo radiobutton, e quando chegar no último, checa o primeiro, e assim sucessivamente.

Ao colocar o mouse sobre a div do slider, o temporizador é cancelado, ao retirar o mouse, o processo se inicia novamente. Para isso usei o método `.hover` do jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   var slids = $(".div-slider [type=radio]"); // busca os radios na div
   var slids_len = slids.length; // conta o número de radios
   var intervalo = 2; // intervalo em segundos
   
   function rodar(){
      var slids_ativo = $(".div-slider [type=radio]:checked")
      .attr("id")
      .match(/\d+/)[0]; // pega o valor numérico do id do radio checado

      if(slids_ativo == slids_len) slids_ativo = 0; // se estiver no último slide, volta pro primeiro

      slids.eq(slids_ativo).prop("checked", true); // checa o radio da vez
   }
   
   var tempo = setInterval(rodar, intervalo*1000); // inicia o temporizador
   
   $(".div-slider").hover(
      function(){ // função quando entra o mouse
         clearInterval(tempo); // cancela o temporizador
      },
      function(){ // função quando retira o mouse
         tempo = setInterval(rodar, intervalo*1000); // reinicia o temporizador
      }
   );
   
});
```

```css
.div-slider{
width: auto;
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
}
.slides-front {
    padding: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 370px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides-front * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides-front input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 370px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    transform: scale(0);

    transition: all .7s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;

    transform: scale(1);

    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: 375px;
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 margin: 0 4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3, {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-slider">
  <ul class="slides-front">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked="">
    <li class="slide-container">
       <div class="slide">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
       </div>
       <div class="nav">
         <label for="img-3" class="prev">‹</label>
         <label for="img-2" class="next">›</label>
       </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/1327-w.jpg">
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">‹</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">›</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3">
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://imagens.canaltech.com.br/123987.210185-JPG.jpg">
        </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">‹</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">›</label>
    </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Certinho parceiro!  Ficou profissa aqui o negócio. Ainda mais com essa configuração que fez  "Ao colocar o mouse sobre a div do slider, o temporizador é cancelado, ao retirar o mouse, o processo se inicia novamente." ---------- cara muito obrigado pela ajuda!